# passing $_POST variable from one page to other

Tags: php

Suppose I have three PHP files: `1.php`, `2.php`, `3.php`

`1.php` sends data with POST method to `2.php`. Now I want `2.php` to send the same data to `3.php` with POST method. I want to link from `2.php` to `3.php` with a single button.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this ? What have you tried ? Show some code.

Comment: i'm new to php . i want to delete an user from database. after taking input i want to show a confirmation page that "are you sure to delete ?" , if YES, then i will pass the $_POST variable to next page to delete the user .

Comment: Please format your post. Come on ... you've been here for over a year. Put some effort in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 4 options on how to do this (first 3 don't require user action, with the 3rd you can auto-submit, but can let the user see it and submit it manually):

- In 2.php you simply use **`include '3.php';`** - thus having access to `$_POST` in 3.php
- Use **[stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)**
- Use **[CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)**
- Re-generate a form with a submit button.

---

```
 <form action="3.php" method="POST">
 <?php
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
     echo "<input type='text' name='{$key}' value='{$value}' />"; // if it's an array, you can serialize it
 }
 ?><input type="submit"></form>
```

You can now show it to the user, or submit it with javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Use anchor tag

```
<a href="3.php?var=<?php $_POST['var']?>"></a>
```

OR

use a form with hidden fields :

```
<input type="hidden" name="var" value="<?php $_POST['var']?>" />
```

and submit the form

Answer (score 1):

You will have read the data in 2.php and create a form with hidden input tags containing that data, which will have 3.php as action source defined.

e.g

```
<form action="3.php">

   <input type=hidden" name="foo" value="bar">
</form>
```

will post 
    { 
     :foo => bar
    }

to 3.php

Maybe you also just consider using a user session and save the values in it